# Getting my jQuery to work on .load() pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my javascript to work on pages I load through the .load command.

```
$("#loadingDockShotPg").load("include/shot_comments.php");
```

I'm doing this to load a subsection of a page, but the problem is, the div within the newly loaded page isn't being affected by my jQuery file that I have in the parent file. What is a better way to load content so that the newly injected can be affected by my javascript?

Comment: You are loading it properly, you just need to write your "my javascript" in such a way that it affects future elements.

Comment: Are we talking events, like click, mouse etc. If so event delegation is the answer, and there are about ten million answers on here already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're issue is with event listeners.

If, for example you're using:

```
$('.something').click(function(){ 
   // DO SOMETHING 
});
```

Try changing it out for:

```
$(document).on('click','.something',function(){ 
   // DO SOMETHING 
});
```

This way the jQuery will listen for any clicks on the document and apply the action to events that match clicking on the `.something` object.

Comment: *"This way the jQuery will listen to the DOM for any elements that are dynamically created"* No, it won't. should be at least `$(document).on("click",".something",function(){...})` `.on` is not a drop-in for `.live`, its syntax is different.

Comment: Now we're getting closer, +1. Now just the last line is partly wrong, as it does'nt actually listen to the DOM, nor does it listen for elements that are dynamic, it just listens for any click on the document, filtering by selector.

Comment: So would I have to do this...

`$(document).live('click', '.subNavi', function(){
    $("#loadingDockShotPg").load("include/shot_comments.php");
});`
Would that solve the problem?

Comment: Here's a fiddle, hopefully it shows what's happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/2JHPD/